# Detect Windows XP for Font Rendering

Tags: windows-xp, rendering, typography, typekit

I've been playing with Typekit for a year now and I've only just noticed how bad fonts look in Windows XP, even when using Chrome. Fonts look ok (not great) on Vista onwards.

Is there a way to detect whether a user is on Windows XP?

I've read a few articles about the different rendering engines on Windows e.g. http://blog.typekit.com/2010/10/21/type-rendering-web-browsers/
http://blog.typekit.com/2010/10/15/type-rendering-operating-systems/#gdi-standard

The reality is that sites still look horrendous with XP and Typekit, even when I have enabled 'cleartype' via display properties.

In conclusion I simply would like to turn off Typekit fonts for XP users, they are un-readable. Normally I would go down the road of feature detection via Modernizr, but I can't detect the font rendering engine so I'm looking for other resorts. Is it possible to detect the operating system?

Comment: You were right, it looks like I jumped the shark with my answer. Unfortunately, I have no idea how to detect the font rendering being used by the OS through the browser. My gut tells me it probably isn't possible, but I've been wrong before!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to find this font smoothing detection technique.

http://www.useragentman.com/blog/2009/11/29/how-to-detect-font-smoothing-using-javascript/

However, typically I've only found font smoothing to be a problem with XP users and various Typekit fonts, so would only advise using if you have a high number of XP users visiting your site (or a website stakeholder - in this case my manager!).